# ag-grid: keep header on top while scrolling

Tags: javascript, ag-grid

I cannot keep table header on top of div while scrolling an ag-grid div. Is there a specific ag- class to use to obtain this?

Thanks

EDIT:

there is the code:

HTML:

```
<md-tab ng-repeat="tab in mbpTabs"> 
        <md-tab-label>{{tab.title}}</md-tab-label>  
        <md-tab-body>
            <div ag-grid="tab.mbpTable.table" class="ag-dark ag-scrolls"></div>
        </md-tab-body> 
    </md-tab>
```

JS grid definition following:

```
this.cols = [{headerName: "Security",marryChildren: true,
    children: [{headerName: "CTRL", field: this.FIELD_KEY_CTRL,hide: true,cellRenderer: MbpTable.prototype.ctrlRenderer.bind(this)},
               {headerName: "Id", field: this.FIELD_KEY_ID,width: 0,hide: true},
               {headerName: "Issuer", field: this.FIELD_KEY_ISSUER,width: 100},
               {headerName: "Cusip", field: this.FIELD_KEY_CUSIP,width: 80,},
               {headerName: "Board Label", field: this.FIELD_KEY_BOARD_LABEL,width: 150}]
},
{headerName: 'Best',marryChildren: true,
    children: [{headerName: "Bid Size", field: this.FIELD_KEY_BEST_BID_SIZE, width: 125,cellClass:"mbp-ag-cell-best-bid",cellRenderer: MbpTable.prototype.szPriceRenderer.bind(this)},
               {headerName: "Bid Price", field: this.FIELD_KEY_BEST_BID_PRICE, width: 125,cellClass:"mbp-ag-cell-best-bid",cellRenderer: MbpTable.prototype.szPriceRenderer.bind(this)},
               {headerName: "Ask Price", field: this.FIELD_KEY_BEST_ASK_PRICE, width: 125,cellClass:"mbp-ag-cell-best-ask",cellRenderer: MbpTable.prototype.szPriceRenderer.bind(this)},
               {headerName: "Ask Size", field: this.FIELD_KEY_BEST_ASK_SIZE, width: 125,cellClass:"mbp-ag-cell-best-ask",cellRenderer: MbpTable.prototype.szPriceRenderer.bind(this)}]
},
{headerName: this.headerMyOrder,marryChildren: true,
    children: [{headerName: "Bid Size", field: this.FIELD_KEY_ORDER_BID_SIZE, width: 80,cellClass:"mbp-ag-cell-order",editable: true,cellRenderer: MbpTable.prototype.bidOrderRenderer.bind(this),cellEditor: "text",newValueHandler: MbpTable.prototype.sizeValueHandler.bind(this)},
               {headerName: "Bid Price", field: this.FIELD_KEY_ORDER_BID_PRICE, width: 80,cellClass:"mbp-ag-cell-order",editable: true,cellRenderer: MbpTable.prototype.bidOrderRenderer.bind(this),cellEditor: "text",newValueHandler: MbpTable.prototype.priceValueHandler.bind(this)},//cellEditor: NumericCellEditor},
               {headerName: "",headerCellTemplate:this.headerMyBidOrder, field: this.FIELD_KEY_ORDER_BID_ACTION,minWidth:18,maxWidth:18,width:18,cellClass:["mbp-ag-cell-order","mbp-ag-cell-order-action"],cellRenderer: MbpTable.prototype.bidOrderRenderer.bind(this)},
               {headerName: "Ask Price", field: this.FIELD_KEY_ORDER_ASK_PRICE, width: 80,cellClass:"mbp-ag-cell-order",editable: true,cellRenderer: MbpTable.prototype.askOrderRenderer.bind(this),cellEditor: "text",newValueHandler: MbpTable.prototype.priceValueHandler.bind(this)},//cellEditor: NumericCellEditor},
               {headerName: "Ask Size", field: this.FIELD_KEY_ORDER_ASK_SIZE, width: 80,cellClass:"mbp-ag-cell-order",editable: true,cellRenderer: MbpTable.prototype.askOrderRenderer.bind(this),cellEditor: "text",newValueHandler: MbpTable.prototype.sizeValueHandler.bind(this)},
               {headerName: "",headerCellTemplate:this.headerMyAskOrder, field: this.FIELD_KEY_ORDER_ASK_ACTION,minWidth:18,maxWidth:18,width:18,cellClass:["mbp-ag-cell-order","mbp-ag-cell-order-action"],cellRenderer: MbpTable.prototype.askOrderRenderer.bind(this)}]}];



    this.table={
        columnDefs: this.cols,
        rowData: MbpTable.prototype.createRndRows(numRows,offset,this),
        rowSelection: 'multiple',
        enableColResize: true,
        enableSorting: true,
        enableFilter: true,
        groupHeaders: true,
        ...
};
```

I omitted following options in table definition here for business reasons.

ag- header classes in CSS have not been modified.

Comment: we're going to need to see your code to help out... Also please look at this [section](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-width-and-height/index.php) of ag-grid that talks about the width and height.

Comment: Please include a code snippet of what you have so far

Comment: the header should stay at the top by default - in fact the only way it'll scroll off the screen is if you're scrolling the whole page, and not just the data within the grid. As the others here have said, you'll probably need to supply an example

Comment: Your question is very vague. Have you put some extra header above the table that you are having trouble with? Or are you talking about the *column* headers? Is the trouble on vertical scroll? or on horizontal scroll?

Comment: Were you able to have a sticky header for ag grid?

Comment: @SeanLandsman Is there a way to have a sticky ag-grid header. I am using autoheight. I have 18 columns and many rows. I have tried `position:sticky; top:0; z-index:1000` It's working for every div other than ag-grid's div

Answer (score -16, accepted):

SOLVED: I needed to add height attribute to the div.

Thank you all

Comment: sorry not clear. Where did you add the height attribute ?

Comment: -1 your answer does answer your question, but is not helpful to others. what div? there are tons of div. which one had to have a height. and what was the hight value?

Comment: it looks like the container div for the ag-grid needs a height.

Answer (score 7):

I want the header in my table always visible even if you scroll down in the window like this. Not sure if this is what the OP want but here is my solution.

[image]

First you need to get the header element and the body element of the table

```js
header = document.querySelector('[ref="headerRoot"]');
body = document.querySelector('[ref="eBodyViewport"]');

// More on this later
original.position = header.style.position;
original.top = header.style.top;
original.zIndex = header.style.zIndex;
```

Add a scroll handler to the `window` object which will execute the logic below every time the user scrolls

```js
window.addEventListener("scroll", () => {
  // More on this below
})
```

The logic is simple. It makes the header sticky or not depend on its position

```js
const shouldStick = header.getBoundingClientRect().top <= 0;
const shouldUnstick = body.getBoundingClientRect().top -
    header.getBoundingClientRect().height > 0;

if (shouldStick) { stick(header); }
if (shouldUnstick) { unstick(header); }
```

Finally add some css style to make it fixed at the top of the window

```js
function stick(header) {
  header.style.position = "fixed";
  header.style.top = "0";
  // this is optional, but if you have other contents that overlap the
  // header you may want to adjust the zIndex accordingly
  header.style.zIndex = "2";
}

function unstick(header) {
  header.style.position = original.position;
  header.style.top = original.top;
  header.style.zIndex = original.zIndex;
}
```

Here is the example implementation in React. All you need to do is copy this hook and paste it in the component's render method. That's it.

```js
import { useCallback, useRef, useEffect } from "react";

const useStickyHeader = () => {
  const headerElementRef = useRef();
  const bodyElementRef = useRef();
  const stickyRef = useRef(false);
  const originalStyles = useRef({ position: "", top: "", zIndex: "" });

  useEffect(() => {
    headerElementRef.current = document.querySelector('[ref="headerRoot"]');
    bodyElementRef.current = document.querySelector('[ref="eBodyViewport"]');

    const header = headerElementRef.current;

    originalStyles.current.position = header.style.position;
    originalStyles.current.top = header.style.top;
    originalStyles.current.zIndex = header.style.zIndex;
  }, []);

  const onScroll = useCallback(() => {
    const header = headerElementRef.current;
    const body = bodyElementRef.current;
    if (!header || !body) return;

    let shouldStick = false;
    let shouldUnstick = false;

    if (!stickyRef.current) {
      shouldStick = header.getBoundingClientRect().top <= 0;
      if (shouldStick) stickyRef.current = true;
    } else {
      shouldUnstick =
        body.getBoundingClientRect().top -
          header.getBoundingClientRect().height >
        0;
      if (shouldUnstick) stickyRef.current = false;
    }

    if (shouldStick) {
      header.style.position = "fixed";
      header.style.top = "0";
      // this is optional, but if you have other contents that overlap the
      // header you may want to adjust zIndex accordingly
      header.style.zIndex = "2";
    }
    if (shouldUnstick) {
      const original = originalStyles.current;
      header.style.position = original.position;
      header.style.top = original.top;
      header.style.zIndex = original.zIndex;
    }
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener("scroll", onScroll);
    return () => window.removeEventListener("scroll", onScroll);
  });

  return stickyRef;
};
```

### Usage

```js
function GridExample() {
  useStickyHeader();

  return (
    <div style={{ width: "100%", height: "100%" }}>
      <div className="grid-wrapper">
        <div
          style={{
            height: "100%",
            width: "100%"
          }}
          className="ag-theme-balham"
        >
          <AgGridReact
            ...
          />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

### Live example

[image: Edit ag-grid-sticky-header]

Comment: This works, but grid jumps a bit when transition occurs from non sticky to sticky and sticky to non sticky

Answer (score 4):

Simple trick is to add css for rows container.

```
.ag-body-viewport {
    overflow: scroll;
    height: 300px;
}
```

Update height or width accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

HTML:
gridAutoHeight = true in ag-grid-angular html tag

TS:
`window.addEventListener('scroll', this.scroll);` **in ngOnit()**

```
scroll = (event: any): void => {
let headerElementRef;
let bodyElementRef;
headerElementRef = document.querySelector('[ref="headerRoot"]');
bodyElementRef = document.querySelector('[ref="eBodyViewport"]');
const nav = headerElementRef;
const body = bodyElementRef;
const offset = nav.getBoundingClientRect();
if (!nav) return;

  if (window.pageYOffset > offset.top && !(body.getBoundingClientRect().top - nav.getBoundingClientRect().height > 0)) {
    nav.style.position = 'fixed';
    nav.style.top = 0;
    nav.style.zIndex = "2";
    nav.style.width = this.totalGridWidth + 'px';
  } else {
    nav.style.position = 'relative';
    nav.style.top = '';
    nav.style.zIndex = "";
    nav.style.width = this.totalGridWidth + 'px';
  }
```

}

Comment: Great and neat solution! Thanks. How do you get totalGridWidth value?